# Why can't I assign a constant C# string to a constant variable from a method that changes the letters from upper to lower case?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

I happened to run into an illogical problem by experimenting around that I can not explain.

```
private const string upperLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private const string lowerLetters = upperLetters.ToLower();
```

So I am aware that constant variables can only take constant values, yes.... but I set them explicitly here and that's good.

Does anyone have an idea?

[What Visual Studio says(German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYDvZ.png)
English: The 'Program.lowerLetters' assigned expression must be costant.

Comment: Since `ToLower` depends on the current culture, and there won't be such a thing until runtime, no you cannot do this. No method calls allowed, even if we did have a way to declare them as safe for invocation at compile time, which we don't.

Comment: `upperLetters.ToLower()` is not a constant, so assigning it to a constant doesn't make sense.

Comment: [Constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1223-constant-expressions)

Comment: lowerLetters can't be a constant as long as it depends on a function result. You can set the upperLetters as a constant but you will have to remove the const declaration in the lowerLetters variable

Comment: If you absolutely needed to, you could still do this at compile time by using a source generator, but obviously that's massive overkill for this particular expression.

Comment: Just make it `static readonly` or in this case hardcode the string: `const string lowerLetters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`

Comment: Also worth noting, `upperLetters.ToLower()` uses the current culture setting at runtime.  Different culture settings -> different results at runtime.  Definitely not a constant. 

Comment: For instance, try with a Turkish culture - you will get `..hıj..`

Answer (score 3):

Constant means constant a the build time (so when the code is compiled, etc.)

`ToLower` is a method, so something that is run not at build time but later, when the program is already built and getting executed.

So `upperLetters.ToLower()` is not constant at build time.